# Get Selected Value in React

Tags: reactjs, mantine

How can I get the id of the value selected from the data array:
 `<Select mt="md" withinPortal data={['Identities', 'Experiences', 'Human Ingenuity', 'Social Organization', 'Sharing the Planet']} placeholder="Pick one" label="Sub-Theme" classNames={classes} />`

I've tried using onChange yet it isnt working, any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<Select
  mt="md"
  withinPortal
  data={[
    { value: 1, label: "Identities" },
    { value: 2, label: "Experiences" },
  ]}
  placeholder="Pick one"
  label="Sub-Theme"
  classNames={classes}
/>;
```

More details on https://mantine.dev/core/select/#data-prop